# Select Query has unexpected multiple records (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I may just be tired, but I can't seem to figure out what is happening.  I have two queries.  Query 1 has 10 fields.  Query 2 has 5 fields.  Fields 1 through 3 are the same in both queries.  I am trying to write a select query and simple add field 5 from Query2 to Query1 so my result should be Query1 with an additional field (Query2.field5).

I join the first 3 fields from both queries and choose select all records in query1 and only those in query2 that match.  I don't know sql, so I use query designer.  I expect to get the same number of records that I have from query 1 but instead I have 3 times or more.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.  I even tried reversing the joins but still seem to get the same extra records.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the query:

The fields that are in common are `DivisionName`, `SupplierID = VendorID` and `CommodityName`.

```
SELECT [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].DivisionName, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].CommodityName, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].SupplierName, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].PartNumber, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].PartDescription, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].BUCode, 
        [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].ProductLine, 
        [Vendor Risk Score Query].VendorScore

FROM [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1] LEFT JOIN [Vendor Risk Score Query] 

ON ([Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].DivisionName = [Vendor Risk Score Query].DivisionName) 
    AND ([Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].SupplierID = [Vendor Risk Score Query].VendorID) 
    AND ([Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].CommodityName = [Vendor Risk Score Query].CommodityName);
```

Comment: can you please show your query?

Comment: show your table structure and indicate their cardinalities. Which are the primary keys of two tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Code was added.  These aren't tables, but queries of queries.  Only Supplier ID is a primary key in a source table... the other fields are not, but I could change it to use IDs instead of names.

Comment: Maybe Query2 should have an extra Field 3 and then Field 1 and Field 4 switch places?  Sarcasm only.  Voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: Smandoli, how can I clarify?  I'm a sql novice - or for that matter, Access novice too.  I was just surprised that the joins I was using would give me more records than I originally had in my query.  It appears to be duplicating records for every join.  If I make it select distinct, I can remove duplicates, but wasn't sure if that truly fixes the issue.

Comment: Ah.  You may have a Cartesian product: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/what-is-join-part-3-cartesian-joins.html

Comment: Smandoli, as you can see from above, I DO have joins, so how can this be a cartesian product?  If it were, I should have more than 3 times the records since there are more than 3 fields in the table.  All I'm trying to do is look up a field in Query2 based on 3 fields and add it to Query1.

Comment: A CP results from ambiguous JOINs, not necessarily the absence of JOINs.  The number of records depends on available permutations and may not be predictable as you propose.

Comment: @User....try using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.  LEFT JOIN gives you records when the right side of the JOIN contains no match.  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070427082608AA7DwSh

Comment: user320, thanks for hanging in there!  Retracted my Close Vote.  Cheers.

Comment: Well, I am not getting any error messages, so how do you propose to prove or disprove this?  And more important, how do I fix it?

Comment: @User...without knowing you data it's hard to tell.  But, the most likely reason for the duplicates is that your join returns more than 1 row from Q2 for Q1

Comment: Agree with MikeTWebb.  His theory is better than Cartesian product. You need to isolate the repeating datum.  Did you try MikeTWebb's suggestion `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Mike/Smandoli.. I did try an inner join and still got thousands of extra records.  Does it matter that these are queries and not tables?   There are no inherent relationships in queries are there?

Comment: You need to post the whole table definitions and sample data.  Without that information, we are just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably because there are multiple records in [Vendor Risk Score Query] matching the condition in [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1]. i.e. if corresponding to one record of [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1] with values:

DivisionName ='TestDiv', SupplierID = 1, CommodityName = 'TestCommodity'

there can be multiple records in [Vendor Risk Score Query] with values

DivisionName ='TestDiv', SupplierID = 1, CommodityName = 'TestCommodity'

then it will return more records than the number of records in [Part Revenue Exposed Query P1]

Comment: Swagata, you won the prize!  Thank you.  I took for granted ( because I was rushing) that the data in the underlying table did not have any duplicate records.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Check you join condition.

```
   AND ([Part Revenue Exposed Query P1].SupplierID = [Vendor Risk Score Query].VendorID)
```

Is supplier to vendor correct?

You said the first three fields are the same.  But it only shows two the same.

Comment: Hi Crafty.  Yes they are the same.

Comment: But they are different names.  That is why I am asking.

Comment: Yes, they are named differently from different tables, but one to many in the original tables.